# using htaccess to redirect old domains to new domain root or directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i have multiple old domains which need to be redirected to a new domain,
either to a specific folder or to the same url parameters on the new domain according to these rules:

1. olddomain1.com/  -> redirect to newdomain.com/a
2. olddomain1.com/parameter=x -> redirect to newdomain.com/parameter=x
3. olddomain2.com/  -> redirect to newdomain.com/b
4. olddomain2.com/parameter=x -> redirect to newdomain.com/parameter=x

so far i have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /a

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /b
```

problem is, if try to load
http://www.olddomain2.com/
it sends me to
http://www.newdomain.com/a

can you help fix this code to work properly ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules :

```
##Redirect "domain1.com" to "/a"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain1\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/a [R,L]
##Redirect "domain1.com/foo" to "newdoamain/foo"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain1\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
##Redirect "domain2.com" to "/a"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain2\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/b  [R,L]
##Redirect "domain2.com/foo" to "newdoamain/foo"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain2\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: works. thanks ! should i add a [R=301,L] instead of [R,L] ?

Comment: **R** is a temp redirect it uses 302 status code by default, you can change **R** to **R=301** to make the redirection permament.